# Infinite Loop - While True [Python]

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, infinite-loop, do-while

Running into the age old problem of the infinite loop...

Writing a text adventure game and have the game mechanics down; map and movement around it. Running into an issue with an infinite loop when I try to implement the other functionality - take items etc.

Below are 2 snippets of the code including the initializing variables, movement code, and the next stage stuff. Below the "......" are where the issue is.

All indentation is aligned as seen.

```
print("Welcome to this most intrepid" + game['name']
+ " your goal; should you dare to continue... is to" + game['goal'])
star_loc = int(game['start'])
curr_loc = star_loc 
character = {'inventory': [], 'location':curr_loc}
x_loc = 1
y_loc = 2
command = input("You are " + map[curr_loc]["desc"] + ' what next? ')

while True:
    command_parts = command.split()
    cmd = command_parts[0]
    print(cmd)
    obj = command_parts[-1]
    print(obj)
    #move around map
    if cmd == 'move' or cmd == 'go' or 'hiddenpath':
        #handles movement on the X plane - East, West
        elif obj == 'east':
            if x_loc == int(game['xsize']): # use the x size the game dict instead, compute the x and y 
                curr_loc = curr_loc - 2
                x_loc = 1
                y_loc = y_loc
                command = input("You are " + map[curr_loc]["desc"] + ' what next? ')
            else:
                curr_loc = curr_loc + 1
                x_loc = x_loc + 1
                y_loc = y_loc
                command = input("You are " + map[curr_loc]["desc"] + ' what next? ')
        elif obj == 'west':
            if x_loc == int(game['xsize']) - 2:
                curr_loc = curr_loc + 2
                x_loc = x_loc = 3
                y_loc = y_loc
                command = input("You are " + map[curr_loc]["desc"] + ' what next? ')
            else:
                curr_loc = curr_loc - 1
                x_loc = x_loc - 1
                y_loc = y_loc
                command = input("You are " + map[curr_loc]["desc"] + ' what next? ')

.................

    if cmd == 'exit':
        print('Goodbye')
        break

    if cmd == 'inv':
        print('You are carrying')
        for item in character['inventory']:
            print('', item)
            continue 

    if cmd == 'goal':
        print(game['goal'])
    else:
        continue
    
    if cmd == 'take':
        if obj in map[curr_loc]['obj']:
            print("You take the " + str(map[curr_loc]['obj'][0]))
            map[curr_loc]['obj'].remove(obj)
            character['inventory'].append(obj)
        continue
```

Major drag... └[∵┌]└[ ∵ ]┘[┐∵]┘

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went through your code and have the following suggestions:

- Make sure your [ssc*c*e](http://www.sscce.org/) is runnable. Specifically, you don't tell us what game looks like.
- instead of multiple equal conditions, which get very cumbersome as you get more clauses, I would use "cmd in ['move', 'go', 'hiddenpath']".
- Instead of putting print statements all over your code, the logging module is your friend.
- `y_loc = y_loc` is a no-op. Get rid of it.
- `command = input("You are " + map[curr_loc]["desc"] + ' what next? ')` does not need to be in every clause, have it after your chain of if/elif statements.

Answer (score 0):

On the line

```
if cmd == 'move' or cmd == 'go' or 'hiddenpath':
```

Change it to

```
if cmd == 'move' or cmd == 'go' or cmd == 'hiddenpath':
```

Comment: or you can change it to



if cmd in [ 'move','go' ,'hiddenpath']: